# Extract the particular string from text file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-2.7

This is the text file we need to extract the particular string from the text file using python or pandas
Single quotes are present in that string

```
>>>>>>>>>>>>
[fgh: hello how r u 'Output Port 1' of 'abcd/cdf' at the home]
[bsdfglsdgjh flgdfhgdfgh]
[fgh: mzjdhxl sldhvlk hvljhxv 'name1']
[bsdfglsdgjh flgdfhgdfgh]
---
[fgh: hello how r u 'Output Port 1' of 'cdf/abc' at the home]
[bsdfglsdgjh flgdfhgdfgh]
[fgh: mzjdhxl sldhvlk hvljhxv 'name2']
[bsdfglsdgjh flgdfhgdfgh]
---
[fgh: hello how r u 'Output Port 1' of 'xyz/pmn' at the home]
[bsdfglsdgjh flgdfhgdfgh]
[fgh: mzjdhxl sldhvlk hvljhxv 'name3']
[bsdfglsdgjh flgdfhgdfgh]
```

The output should be

```
name1 : abcd/cdf
name2 : cdf/abc
name3 : xyz/pmn
```

Comment: Please include code you have tried.

Comment: pandas is a python library, so "using python or pandas" means using anything from python. And there're many ways to do this with or without pandas. If this is an exercise, make sure to state clearly the constraints so you get the solution you are looking for.

Comment: But first read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Answer (score 0):

the answer to your question is this:

```
with open("filename.txt", "r") as file:
    strt = file.read()

a = strt.split("---")
for item in a:
    b = item.split("'")
    a = b[5].replace(">>>>>>>>>>>>", "")
    print(f"{b[5]} : {b[3]}")
```

Put all your content into filename.txt and run it.

Comment: For large data IndexError: list index out if range error is coming

Answer (score 0):

do you know about [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#)? While not overly performant they are exactly the type of thing you would use in such a situation.

something along the following lines should give you an option to find the names.

```
import re

match_lines_with_content = re.compile(r"^[fhg:")
match_name_designated_by_single_quote = re.compile(r"mzjdhxl sldhvlk hvljhxv (?P<name>[^']+)")

for line in <input_lines>:
   if match_lines_with_content.matches(line):
        name = match_name_designated_by_single_quote.match(line).group(0)
```

Comment: `mzjdhxl sldhvlk hvljhxv` is probably a placeholder to indicate variable text.

Comment: Agreed, though I did not feel confident enough to assume single quotes were the sole identifying elements for the searched string. Do you have a suggestion for a better regex? `r"[^']+(?P<name>[^']+)"` ?

Answer (score 0):

just open and read each line and get the values you need

```
with open("example.txt", "r") as example:
nameNum = 1
for i in example.readlines():
    
    if "Output Port 1" in i:
        new = i.split("'")
        index = new.index("Output Port 1")
        print(f'name{nameNum} : ' + new[index+2])
        nameNum += 1
```